# MongoDB returning undefined object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

New to express and mongo but I've been trying to pull from my a Local MongoDB database hosted on my own device using express.js .find() function, so far ive had no luck. I get '[]' back in the console, it may be an empty string or an undefined object. Ive tried many things
-changing the schema or removing it all together when defining my model

- i have confirmed that the data does exist in my database and i can see it on compass and with mongosh
- i have tried checking my firewall and network setting to make sure that windows is not blocking my server from communicating with my database
  -I have tried sending the information as a json object instead and i still get the same thing
  here is my code:

```
const express = require('express'); 
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express(); 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const uri = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Test'
mongoose.connect(uri);
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('connected', ()=> {
    console.log('Success');
});
db.on('error', (err)=> {
    console.log('error', err);
});
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', ()=> {
    console.log('disconnected');
});

const Model = mongoose.model('model', new mongoose.Schema({}));
app.use(express.json());


db.Model.find()
    .lean()
    .exec()
    .then(data => {
        if (data){
            console.log('data:', data);
        }  else{
            console.log('no data');
        }
  })
app.get('/', async(req, res) => {
        try {
        const posts = await Model.find({});
        res.send(posts)
    } catch (error) {//error block
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    } 
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: The fact that you get an empty array back `[]` means that the query was a success in the sense that you connected to a mongodb instance but nothing was found. Can you tell me what is the name of the database you are looking at in compass and what is the name of the collection your data is stored in? These two thing are case sensitive so it's important you get these correct.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're attempting to run the Model.find() query outside of an endpoint or route handler, which causes it to execute before the connection to the database is fully established. As a result, you are getting an empty array ([]) as the initial output.
Here's the updated code :

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const uri = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Test';

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
});

db.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('MongoDB connection error:', err);
});

// Define your schema and model
const modelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // write your schema fields here...
    
});

const Model = mongoose.model('Model', modelSchema);

app.use(express.json());

// here's your endpoint to fetch data
app.get('/api/data', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await Model.find({}).lean().exec();
        res.json(data);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```